# Handling failure with Azkaban

Tags: azkaban

There is a way to control what happens in Azkaban after a job fails,
I mean doing specific thing if specific job fails,
Lets say  a load to hive is failed and i want to send error to splank
Is it possible?
Or should i create specific job that will to the insert and handle the failure like python

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way I handle this is to have a following job that runs a script with the `command` job type. I have my script check for the error condition and then perform and action *only* if the error is found.

```
#!/bin/bash
check=${./_check_script.sh $arg1 $arg2}
if [ -z $check ]; then 
  echo "ERROR FOUND"
  ./_error_action.sh $arg1 $arg2
fi
```

Note that you have to allow script execution by the Azkaban user (`chmod +x`) for any scripts in before you run them. They do not inherit permissions due to the use of `.zip` as the upload format.

```
type=command
command=chmod +x _alert_for_error.sh
command.1=chmod +x _check_script.sh
command.2=chmod +x _error_action.sh
command.3=./_alert_for_error.sh
```